# Code Optimization: Create a method for recurring procedures

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, optimization, methods

I am trying to optimize this code (for recurring procedures in C# (WPF)). Is there an opportunity to create one method, that does all this code? Just a bit smarter? I do not want to copy and paste this code into `DoMyCode()`. My problem is, that there are 20 `ListViewItems` I click. Every `ListViewItem` does the same (just with another `Label`).

```
private void listViewItem_Group0_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Position.Content = label_Group0.Content.ToString();
    SetDataGridItems(label_Group0.Content.ToString());
}

private void listViewItem_Group1_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Position.Content = label_Group1.Content.ToString();
    SetDataGridItems(label_Group1.Content.ToString());
}

private void listViewItem_Group2_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Position.Content = label_Group2.Content.ToString();
    SetDataGridItems(label_Group2.Content.ToString());
}

private void listViewItem_Group3_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Position.Content = label_Group3.Content.ToString();
    SetDataGridItems(label_Group3.Content.ToString());
}

private void listViewItem_Group4_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Position.Content = label_Group4.Content.ToString();
    SetDataGridItems(label_Group4.Content.ToString());
}
```

My XAML code looks like this:

```
<ListViewItem Selected="listViewItem_Group0_Selected">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Apptivities;component/Images/interessenten_.png" Stretch="None" />
        <Label Content="Interessenten Sponsoren" Name="label_Group0" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem Selected="listViewItem_Group1_Selected">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Apptivities;component/Images/interessenten_.png" Stretch="None" />
        <Label Content="Interessenten Teilnehmer" Name="label_Group1" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem Selected="listViewItem_Group2_Selected">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Apptivities;component/Images/keine_kooperation.png" Stretch="None" />
        <Label Content="Keine Kooperation" Name="label_Group2" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem Selected="listViewItem_Group3_Selected">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Apptivities;component/Images/potenzielle_.png" Stretch="None" />
        <Label Content="Potenzielle Sponsoren" Name="label_Group3" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem Selected="listViewItem_Group4_Selected">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Apptivities;component/Images/potenzielle_.png" Stretch="None" />
        <Label Content="Potenzielle Teilnehmer" Name="label_Group4" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

Do you know, how to do this?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Is there an opportunity to create one method, that does all this code? Just a bit smarter? :-)

Comment: Yes, you can probably make it into one method.  But this question is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: I do not want to copy and paste this code into `DoMyCode()`. My problem is, that there are 20 `ListViewItems` I click. Every `ListViewItem` does the same (just with another `Label`). Do you understand?

Comment: Can you show your Xaml code please, so that we can know where exactly are these labels

Comment: Can you maintain a lookup of sender to action to take, and look up what to do based on the sender in a single method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code can be easily converted in one method based on sender object

```
 private void listViewItem_Group_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem lv = sender as ListViewItem;
            DockPanel dockpanel = (lv.Content) as DockPanel;
            Label label = (dockpanel.Children[1]) as Label;
            label_Position.Content = label.Content.ToString();
            SetDataGridItems(label.Content.ToString());

        }
```

Change all the Selected events to a common event as "listViewItem_Group_Selected" and as the dockpanel is the child of ListViewItem, Label can be read by iterating through the dockpanel child controls.

Answer (score 0):

You could reference all listviewitem selected events in your front-end  (XAML/WinForm) to just one code-behind method and then distinguish between them using the sender object.